# jQuery - if exists, get value of document.domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, same-origin-policy

How to check if `document.domain` is set on a page, and return it's value?

**Update**

before the barrage of negativity, I was inquiring about how to get the document.domain value when it's been explicitly set.

What I ended up with was

`if(window.location.hostname !== document.domain)`

this will tell you if document.domain has been set explicitly on a page.

Comment: uhm... `document.domain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(window.location.hostname !== document.domain)
```

Is how to check if document.domain is being explicitly set - by comparing the document.domain variable against the hostname, if the above returns as true, then document.domain is being reassigned on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you access any variable.

What do you want to do with it? "Return" it where?

As an example, you can trivially pop it up in a message box:

```
alert(document.domain);
```

Or do whatever you like with it.

If it's not set, the result will be `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

uhm... you simply do

`document.domain`